# I have a Blazor server app.How can I add a live chart into my Razor page?

Tags: c#, razor, charts, blazor

I have a Blazor server app.I have to add a live chart into my razor page that will get the data from the related razor.cs C# code. With my C# code I am reading the Cpu load of a remote PC in 1 second intervall. How can I visualise the CPU load live on my razor page?

Comment: Use SignalR for live update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is using a component library that solves the JavaScript part for you. For example: [Blazorise](https://bootstrapdemo.blazorise.com/tests/livecharts).
Else, you'll have to arrange the JS part yourself using [JSInterop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Thank you so much.That was the answer i was waiting for.